# On toggle Hide/show

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code.
If a user press on lets say `burger` and add it into `session` basket. The reload of page doesn't open the current Window View(Toggle)

How can I make it open the current again on reload...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```

This is how to show/hide the text.

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('sandwich');"></a> 
<div id="sandwich" class="hidden">
Here you go 1 </div>

<a href="javascript:unhide('burger');"></a> 
<div id="burger" class="hidden">
Here you go 2 </div>
```

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/5ZpuF/

Comment: If what you're really after is persistency, you'll need persistent storage.

Comment: It opens on click but not on reload. Try to reload the page.

Comment: Can you show me some codings...

Comment: HTML is stateless, when you reload a page it's like starting from scratch, there is no persistency.

Comment: Can you show me some recoding of this script..

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Things like this are not persistent across page reload / refresh.

There are two basic approaches to it:

- Session cookie and session on server, communication via AJAX
- Store all in a cookie

Both require some extra work, but it's unavoidable.

For the cookie part, there's a nice jQuery plugin called `jquery.cookie`.